# How to change default settings of sbt-thrift plugin in SBT?

Tags: sbt, thrift

I am using [sbt-thrift](https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift) plugin **0.6** with SBT **0.12** and I need to change the resource directory, source directory, output directory and other settings in my build configuration.

It doesn't seem to work as mentioned in [README](https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift).

Can someone tell me how to do this thing?

Comment: If you let me know what settings correspond to *"resource directory, source directory, output directory"* I'd change my answer appropriately.

Comment: I use scala 0.12 and sbt-thrift 0.6
I am working with several modules. I need thrift for one module only. And I need to keep my thrift files in resource directory of that module. Then the output directory should be src/main/java

Comment: It's pretty much similar to SBT 0.13 with the only exception of using full build configuration rather than build.sbt in a project's directory (to scope the settings defined to the project). Are the modules under a single multi-build configuration? (in other words, is there a root aggregating project? You should use `project/*.scala` with `lazy val [project-name] = Project(...).settings(...)` to scope thrift plugin to the project.

Comment: See update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### SBT 0.13 + sbt-thrift 0.7

**NOTE** Below is the same configuration for SBT **0.12** and sbt-thrift **0.6**

I use SBT **0.13.1** and hence had to use `sbt-thrift` **0.7** from http://bigtoast.github.io/repo/com/github/bigtoast/sbt-thrift_2.10_0.13/0.7/.

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "bigtoast-github" at "http://bigtoast.github.com/repo/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.bigtoast" % "sbt-thrift" % "0.7")
```

**build.sbt**

```
import com.github.bigtoast.sbtthrift.ThriftPlugin

seq(ThriftPlugin.thriftSettings: _*)
```

With the above build configuration, you may want to look at https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift/blob/master/src/main/scala/ThriftPlugin.scala for possible tasks and settings (I have not checked whether [README.md](https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift#thrift-plugin-for-sbt-012)'s fully correct).

There's `source-directory` setting to set *"Source directory for thrift files. Defaults to src/main/thrift"*.

```
> thrift:source-directory
[info] C:\dev\sandbox\thrift\src\main\thrift
```

To change the value use the following:

```
ThriftPlugin.thriftSourceDir := sourceDirectory.value / "my-own-source-dir"
```

and `reload` so the setting changes (*react*) accordingly:

```
> thrift:source-directory
[info] C:\dev\sandbox\thrift\src\my-own-source-dir\main\thrift
```

Please note that all the settings and tasks belong to the `thrift` config.

### SBT 0.12 + sbt-thrift 0.6

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "bigtoast-github" at "http://bigtoast.github.com/repo/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.bigtoast" % "sbt-thrift" % "0.6")
```

Since OP asked about multi-project build configuration, below is the definition of two projects with one configured with a custom value for `thriftSourceDir`.

**project/MyBuild.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import com.github.bigtoast.sbtthrift.ThriftPlugin._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val thriftS = Defaults.defaultSettings ++
    thriftSettings ++
    Seq(
      thriftSourceDir <<= sourceDirectory(_ / "my-own-source-dir")
    )

  lazy val thriftP = Project("thriftProject", 
    file("."),
    settings = thriftS
  )

  lazy val someP = Project("some-other-project",
    file("some-other-project")
  )
}
```

With the build configuration, sbt shell gives you the following:

```
> sbt-version
[info] 0.12.4
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/thrift-0.12/
[info]     some-other-project
[info]   * thriftProject
> thrift:source-directory
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/thrift-0.12/src/my-own-source-dir/main/thrift
> thriftProject/thrift:source-directory
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/thrift-0.12/src/my-own-source-dir/main/thrift
> some-other-project/thrift:source-directory
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/thrift-0.12/some-other-project/src
```