# Removing "gen-java" prefix from auto-generated Java files with sbt-thrift in SBT 0.12?

Tags: sbt, thrift

I am working with [sbt-thrift](https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift) plugin **0.6** and SBT **0.12**.

In my thrift files I have mentioned the namespace as below.

```
namespace java abc.xyz
//some 
//thrift 
//codes
```

But the generated files goes to

```
gen-java/abc/xyz
```

(`gen-java` prefix is added automatically). How can I change this into

```
abc/xyz
```

?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `-out <outdir>` option which does exactly that. In your case, specify the current folder `.` as the outdir.

Note that, unlike with the automatically generated `gen-*` folders, the outdir directory must exist. In other words, you have to make sure the folder is created *before* calling the Thrift compiler.

The `--help` option gives more information about all the other switches.

---

Regarding SBT, if the information on https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift is true, then you should contact the author of that software to add the option `thriftJavaOutputDir` as it seems missing.

BTW, the question looks very much like a duplicate of [How to change default settings of sbt-thrift plugin in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825063/how-to-change-default-settings-of-sbt-thrift-plugin-in-sbt) I would recommend to NOT ask ten thousand copies of similar questions on SO.

Comment: can you add an example. In sbt, i have to run thrift:generate-java to compile the IDL files. where should I put "-o <outdir>" at. I put it at the beginning and at end, it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know about SBT, but `-o` is a switch that you pass to the Thrift compiler executable.

Comment: Actually it's `-out`, not `-o`. Slight difference here, sorry.