# thrift:generate-python generates no Python files in SBT

Tags: sbt, thrift

I use [sbt-thrift](https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift) **0.6** and I've got the following in the build definition:

```
thriftPythonEnabled := true,
thriftPythonOutputDir <<= sourceDirectory(_ / "python")
```

When I run `thrift:generate-python` it generates nothing. `thrift:generate-java` works fine.

Can someone tell me what I have to do to enable the Python support in the plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing "gen-java" prefix from auto-generated Java files with sbt-thrift in SBT 0.12?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844241/removing-gen-java-prefix-from-auto-generated-java-files-with-sbt-thrift-in-sbt)

Answer (score 1):

You miss `Thrift` config in your setting.

Give the following a try (using SBT **0.12** syntax):

```
thriftPythonEnabled in Thrift := true,
thriftPythonOutputDir in Thrift <<= sourceDirectory(_ / "python")
```