# Enabling Python code generation using sbt-thrift plugin in SBT?

Tags: sbt, thrift

In my project, I'm using [sbt-thrift](https://github.com/bigtoast/sbt-thrift) plugin to thrift code generation.

According to the readme, java code generation is already enabled by default, but other code generations are disabled by default. To enable it, I've used

```
thriftPythonEnabled := true
```

in my `Build.scala` file. It doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone explain what is the problem with the configuration?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? I don't use the plugin and thrift in general and hence the question to reproduce the issue. Can you verify if the setting is actually set for the project where the thrift code is? Could you post the entire `Build.scala`? Is this for SBT 0.12 or 0.13? Post `project/plugins.sbt`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question got upvoted it's not possible to mark it as a duplicate of [thrift:generate-python generates no Python files in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872682/thriftgenerate-python-generates-no-python-files-in-sbt) where I wrote:

You miss `Thrift` config in your setting.

Give the following a try:

```
thriftPythonEnabled in Thrift := true,
thriftPythonOutputDir in Thrift <<= sourceDirectory(_ / "python")
```